# Vector equation of final velocity of two spheres after a fully elastic collision in 3D space

Tags: momentum, vectors, collision, elasticity

I'm experimenting with 3D graphics a bit and I'm trying to implement collision between some fully elastic moving spheres. The problem is I couldn't find a proper equation for collision in 3D space.

The wikipedia page for elastic collision contains equations for linear and collision in 2D plane. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision

Comment: I am sure there is an easier way than this, but have a look, or search for vector cross product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

Comment: @CountTo10 I don't understand why you've given me link of cross product. I do know how to calculate cross products, but how will it help me deriving the equation for final velocity after elastic collision?

Comment: I think the answer will be the same as that for the 2D problem if you adjust your plane of calculation to be the plane of incidence.

Comment: Using an impact parameter approach, it is fairly straightforward going from 2D to 3D using the spherical symmetry of the 3D situation (getting $2\pi r dr$ instead of $r$).

Comment: @garyp I've thought about it, but it seemed a little more complex than that. What if the velocities are in parallel planes(in less distance than the sum of the radius of the two spheres)?

Comment: @JonCuster Can you please elaborate your comment, as an answer if possible?

Comment: The math gets a little ugly. In the 2D case, for an impact parameter of $b$ in the center-of-mass frame you can calculate the angles that the incident and target circles have after the collision. Considering only the scattered circle, you have some $b + \delta b$ scatters in to $\Theta + \delta\Theta$. Going to 3D, nothing about the calculation of $\Theta$ from $b$ changes, but the total cross sectional area that can cause such a scattering event _increases_ with $b$ via $2\pi b \delta b$ since it is circularly symmetric around the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about the cross product reference, it's difficult to judge who knows what about a subject, and I usually get it wrong.

If this answer  is no good to you, I will delete it:

This is all taken from [3-D collisions modelling](https://www.atmos.illinois.edu/courses/atmos100/userdocs/3Dcollisions.html) , so my apologies if it's familiar to you.

> When two particles contact each other, the force between the molecules is directed along an imaginary line that connects their centers. If you rotate your frame of reference so this center-line is along the x-axis, this is simply a 1-D collision problem, where in an elastic collision, the forces acting upon each other are just switched (in equal mass cases -- this code does mass-weight the vector switching for colliders with unequal masses, which is not reflected in the equations).
>
> Step 1: Determine the 3D angle between the two colliders.

[image]

> Step 2: Calculate the colliders' force vectors towards each other.

[image]

> Step 3: Decompose this vector into x'-y'-z' components, where x' is aligned with the center-line.

[image]

[image]

Vector fields

Vectors are defined in spherical coordinates by (ρ,θ,φ), where

$ρ$ is the length of the vector,$θ$ is the angle between the positive Z-axis and the vector in question $(0 ≤ θ ≤ π)$, and $φ$ is the angle between the projection of the vector onto the X-Y-plane and the positive X-axis $(0 ≤ φ < 2π)$.

by:

$${\displaystyle {\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}}={\begin{bmatrix}\rho \sin \theta \cos \phi \\\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi \\\rho \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}}.}$$

Above is from Wikipedia, so it does not take into account his remark about x' being aligned along the center  line.

> Step 4: Before switching the colliders' force vectors, determine the force vector normal to the center-line so we can recompose the new collision.

[image]

[image]

> Step 5: Switch the colliders' force vectors.

[image]

> Step 6: Compose the new vectors into a new velocity:

[image]1)

> Assumptions:
>
> 1) All collisions are elastic.
>
> 2) All particles are perfect spheres.
>
> 3) That the objects can come closer than the sum of the radii of the two particles.
>
> 4) Only two particles can collide at a time. If three technically hit together, the particle with the lowest array index will collide with the second lowest, then separately with the next lowest. Then, if the second is still close enough to the third, a third collision will result.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't take any offense, I was just bewildered that if there was any easy derivation through cross products. This answer is very helpful, but I don't understand the functionality of decomposition in step 3, can you please explain it?

Comment: Ok, this is completely new to me, (that's why I thought in physics terms about cross products), but I am going to read up a bit more on it now. Obviously he is switching between cartesian and spherical systems, but rather than waste your time with my guesses, let me see if I can find another source.