# Ball falling onto a ball at an angle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-kinematics

Ignoring air resistance, I am attempting to create a simple model of what would happen if a ball were dropped on top of another ball on earth. The question is how to understand the interactions between the balls in these circumstances. In the model, I am accounting for the coefficients of static and kinetic friction. Only one ball—sphere $S_A$ with independent force $\overrightarrow{F_A}$—is *a*bove in the air, and the other ball—sphere $S_B$ with force $\overrightarrow{F_B}=0\hat{\text{i}}+0\hat{\text{j}}$—is neither moving nor stationary *b*elow on the ground.

[image]

My initial thought is to model this situation like a ramp where the slope of the ramp is normal/perpendicular to a line which intersects both circles' centers.

[image]

After the balls collide, $S_A$ now has force $\overrightarrow{F_{AC}}$ and $S_B$ now has force $\overrightarrow{F_{BC}}$. My guess is that that the normal force $\overrightarrow{F_N}$ of the ramp is applied to the force $\overrightarrow{F_B}$ on the ball $S_B$ on the ground to produce $\overrightarrow{F_{BC}}$. I know that the force of a ball rolling down a stationary inclined plane is $\overrightarrow{F}=mg{\cdot}\cos(
\theta)\hat{\text{i}}-mg{\cdot}\sin(
\theta)\hat{\text{j}}$, but I am unsure about a moving inclined plane. Given Newton's third law, I would also guess that the force applied to the dropped ball $S_A$ will be in the opposite direction, however, I am still stuck at the moving inclined plane. Am I on the right track? How would one derive the full equations for this motion?

This is not assigned homework and I am not asking for only the solution, rather I seek comprehension of this model for both myself and others who struggle to understand this.

Comment: "Is neither moving nor stationary..." What is the second ball doing then, also I would suggest a better letter for the spheres than F as that typically denotes forces.

Comment: @Triatticus I apologize for my confusing terminology (I am not always the best at using the proper words). What I meant by "not stationary" is that the ball is not glued/nailed/fixed/whatever to the ground. The ball on the ground is just sitting there and not moving until it is impacted. For my edification, how do you suggest I describe this better? Thank you.
Next, I used F because the vector forces of the balls are of primary relevance to this question, so the forces of the balls best describes them. To disambiguate my question, which letter should I use instead of F to describe the balls?

Comment: @Triatticus Thank you (my previous comment exceeded the word limit, so this is a continuation).

Comment: You could use the letter B for each ball, and F for the forces acting on them, or even S for sphere. As for the second ball, you could just say the second ball rests on a surface and is free to move if struck by the first ball.

Comment: @Triatticus I have applied your suggestions. Thank you so much for your constructive criticism. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you looked at the many questions on this site which explain how to handle collisions of extended rigid bodies, including effect on rotation?

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Comment: See eg [Vector equation of final velocity of two spheres after a fully elastic collision in 3D space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/286987). See also Game Development SE which is more appropriate for developing code for simulations. However learning from an online tutorial for gaming is better than trawling through questions and answers. For example try [topta video game physics tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/game/video-game-physics-part-i-an-introduction-to-rigid-body-dynamics).

Comment: @sammygerbil Thank you very much for your suggestion, and your link is very helpful. Through my experiences, I have found that posting my problem in a forum most relevant to the aspect that I am lacking often gives me the best result. In this case, I feel that although an explanation by a fellow coder will do much to help me understand the coding aspect, I already understand the coding aspect and the coder may skimp on the physics aspect. Further, I doubt I'll get any answers other than suggests for a physics engine I should try in a coding forum--something which does not help me one bit.

Comment: @JackGiffin What you are trying to learn will take more than could be explained in a single question on this forum. You really need a tutorial, because you seem to have several things to learn such as conservation of momentum, coefficient of restitution, rotational dynamics. See eg Khan Academy on YouTube.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thank you so much for your insights. I shall research those topics. Thank you!